# Oracle VARRAY in Hibernate Function

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Hibernate named native query to access an oracle function...

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "getProducts", 
    query = "{ ? = call prefix.get_products(:code, :productGroups) }", 
    callable = true, 
    resultClass = Product.class
)
```

Unfortunately, `productGroups` is of type `VARRAY` (`ARRAYTYPENUMBER`, a number `VARRAY`). For a normal entity mapping, I could simply create a `UserType` (been there, done that) and map that via `@Type`, but the big question is...

How can I put this piece of information ("use this `UserType`") into my `@NamedNativeQuery` ?

Edit: I tried it via registering a TypeDef in my entity...

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery( ... see above ...)
@TypeDef(defaultForType = IdList.class, typeClass = ArrayUserType.class)
public class Product {
```

...but unfortunately, this doesn't work, since the `ArrayUserType` is never initialized and never used, even when I give an `IdList` object as the parameter for `productGroups` in the query.

Also adding it via (manually `@Bean` initialized) `LocalSessionFactory.registerTypeOverride` does not work, but there I can give only keys anyway, no default java types.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global UserType converter, not just on your mappings like below

```
 localSessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration().getTypeResolver().registerTypeOverride(UserType, keys);
```

this will be applied to all queries (including native sql). Just pass in a proper userType and keys and it should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, no localSessionFactoryBean seems to exist in my Spring Boot 1.4.0-RELEASE context. I tried @TypeDef on my Entity, but this seems to be completely ignored.

Comment: localSessionFactoryBean = session factory in your application. If you are using hibernate then you must have already configured the sessionFactory in your app

Comment: I thought so, too, but unfortunately that bean does not exist in the context, while Hibernate works... Didn't configure Hibernate explicitly, that happens automatically via Spring Boot.

Comment: I can of course create one manually and use that (Hibernate 5 doesn't seem to have TypeResolver anymore, just directly registerTypeOverride), but it still doesn't work. Probably the keys are wrong...